# Core Plot Interactive graph hangs in ios 6

Tags: core-plot

I am using core plot library to draw graphs in my application. When I try to move the plot point application does not respond to it. It hangs completely blocking every action.

Comment: We need more information. What do you mean by "move the plot point"? How are you moving it? What troubleshooting steps have you tried?

Comment: Also, if this is a bug with the project, file a report on the project site, not here.

Comment: @EricSkroch Graph is interactive, means USER can move the points on graph whereevr he wants to move it along Y axis of graph.

Comment: @BradLarson: I am not sure if this is bug in core plot project, because same project is working fine on ios 5.0 and below. Wondering, if anything is changed in ios 6

Comment: While debugging I found that drawInContext method of my Annotation Object gets called multiple times

Comment: @SureshJambhalkar, that's normal, but not ideal. I'm working on reducing the amount of drawing required for labels and other annotations, but don't have anything ready for public use yet. Do you have a lot of annotations, axis labels, and/or plot data labels? Does the problem happen on a device (which one(s)?) and/or the simulator?

Comment: @EricSkroch: Yes, I have lot of annotations and axis labels. Problem occured only on ios 6 Device and simulator and not on previous versions

Comment: Does the rendering eventually catch up allowing the app to respond again? Does it ever crash?

Comment: App did not crash, but it got freeze after I touched grpah point.

Comment: I was using transform on my view in drawInContext method, I commented it and I dont know why, but my problem got resolved. Now app works fine